# focus default button on bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

I have an Angular2 application that I am using the bootstrap model to display a confirm dialog to the User using data-toggle as below

```
<button *ngIf="!profileModel.isDeleted" type="button" data-toggle="modal" [hidden]="profileId == null" data-target="#confirmProfileDeleteModal"
    class="left-align drs-btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="confirmProfileDeleteModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" style="margin-top: 20%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <p><i class="fa fa-4x fa-exclamation-circle"></i>If you continue the selected record will be deleted</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>If you continue the selected record will be deleted.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" (click)="deleteProfile()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All works find and the dialog shows however I would like to be able to focus on the primary button in the dialog (e.g. the button with class btn-primary)

I have tried adding script in the ngAfterViewInit to handle the shown.bs.modal event and set focus on the primary button but this does not work

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
            $(this).find(".btn-primary").focus() // also tried wrapping in setTimeout
        });
    });
}
```

What I would like to know is has anyone encountered this and how they were able to focus a button on a bootstrap modal?

**EDIT**

It should also be noted that I have this code in the app.component.ts file, following the answer from @Kevin I tried moving the code into the component class for the profile and this does now work.

What I dont want to have to do though is have this code in all my components and rather have the code in one place that applies globally to all modal dialogs, how could this be accomplished with Angular2?

Comment: Why are you using `jquery`

Comment: @Aravind how would you suggest I achieve this?

Comment: To have this applied globally: in angular's index.html file, put your jquery code in a script tag right before the end of the body tag.  *note: @kevin's answer didn't work for me, angular4/bootstrap4.

Answer (score 1):

[I would just comment this but I don't have enough reputation yet]

Your code looks right, but you're using both ngAfterViewInit and $(document).ready. Try calling the handler only once the page loads.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
        $(this).find(".btn-primary").focus() // also tried wrapping in setTimeout
    });
};
```